# Change popover arrow direction - iOS

Tags: uipopovercontroller

How can I change the position of the popover arrow, instead of it being in the up and centre, I want it to be up and to the right.

**NOTE:**
My navigation bar is a custom nav bar.

I tried the solution [referenced in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401747/uipopovercontroller-altering-location-of-uipopoverarrowdirection) but I cann't get it to change its position correctly. it's always centred.

Answer (score 1):

For more control you might consider not using a popover at all.

Change the value to NO:

```
- (BOOL)popoverSupported
{
    return NO;
}
```

in the file

```
CDVCamera.m
```